# where is SBT file in my kafka download?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apache-kafka

I'm trying to install Kafka on a Digitalocean droplet with this guide:

https://kafka.apache.org/08/quickstart.html

So, I'm downloading the last release: http://ftp.unicamp.br/pub/apache/kafka/0.8.1.1/kafka-0.8.1.1-src.tgz

But after TAR file and enter directory, it has no SBT file to run.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, use binary distribution -- it's ready to be consumed as soon as you unpack it.

Secondly, you can't find sbt file because recently (0.8.1+) kafka project migrated to gradle (a different build tool) and now you have to use gradle commands:

```
./gradlew clean
./gradlew releaseTarGz
```

(this will produce the very same binary release I've mentioned above).

Check out [README.md file inside the project](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/README.md) for a full guide on gradle tasks.